# Type mismatch for Currency variable/data field in VBA (Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a small application in Microsoft Access using VBA. I've encountered what I suspect is a simple issue and I can't figure it out. I have this event on a button-click:

```
Private Sub CalculateCredit_Click()

    Dim TotalCredit As Currency
    TotalCredit = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT SUM(Credit) FROM EmployeeCredit")

End Sub
```

The EmployeeCredit.Credit field's data type is Currency; my TotalCredit variable is of type Currency. When I click the button, I get a compile error that there is a type mismatch between EmployeeCredit.Credit and TotalCredit.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a recordset to a Currency variable.

Retrieve the first field:

```
TotalCredit = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT SUM(Credit) FROM EmployeeCredit")(0).Value
```

Or use `DSum`:

```
TotalCredit = DSum("Credit", "EmployeeCredit")
```